# After updating to 5.9, when the posts page is loaded in the browser it uses wp-includes/template-canvas.php?

Tags: posts

My WordPress site uses the following:

- Header.php file from the theme.
- Footer.php file from the theme.
- Apart from the Posts Page, the rest of the site makes use of Gutenberg blocks (not header or footer area).
- The posts page uses the site's index.php file at wp-content/themes/meow/index.php

When I updated the site to 5.9, the posts page no longer looked the same. I checked what file loads when the posts page is viewed in the browser:

1. Before the update to 5.9, the site loads: wp-content/themes/meow/index.php.
2. After the update, the site loads: wp-includes/template-canvas.php

I thought WordPress was supposed to be future-proof. How can I make use of index.php, instead of template-canvas.php, when the site is updated to 5.9?

Comment: Are you using a child theme?

Comment: @SallyCJ I'm not using a child theme.

Comment: Is it a custom theme you developed on your own? And, "the posts page no longer looked the same" - you mean the single post pages like `example.com/hello-world` *only* (i.e. other pages like category archives and search results pages are not using the `template-canvas.php`)? Also, "I checked what file loads" - how did you check? Try adding a dummy text (e.g. `test123`) to the `index.php` file and see if the text is showing on the single post pages?

Answer (score 0):

this happens because wp_enable_block_templates() is enabled.
Try to navigate to wp-includes/theme-templates.php and comment that function, its placed at the end of the file.

Let me know if it worked, good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the solution, but this one is better than hacking the core files
you can use this code in your functions.php to disable  block theme support

```
function action_remove_block_templates()
{
    remove_theme_support('block-templates');
}
add_action('after_setup_theme', 'action_remove_block_templates', 15);
```